# What is weak monotonicity?

Tags: microeconomics

Which one's the correct definition of weak monotonicity?

1. $(x \geq y \implies x \succeq y) \land (x > y \implies x \succ y)$
2. $x \geq y \implies x \succeq y$

The first definition doesn't allow $(3,3,1) \sim (1,1,0)$ while the second does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Weak) monotonicity captures the idea of a preference being *non-decreasing*, namely, if bundle $x$ contains no less quantities of each good than bundle $y$, then $x$ is at least as good as $y$. Therefore it is consistent with the second definition you have.

In contrast, strict (or strong) monotonicity captures the idea of a preference being *strictly increasing*; that is, if a bundle $x$ contains no less quantities of each good and strictly more quantities for some goods than bundle $y$, then $x$ is strictly better than $y$. This is commonly defined (e.g. in MWG or Kreps) as

> $(x\ge y \wedge x\ne y)\Rightarrow x\succ y$.

Your definition (1) of monotonicity is of an intermediate "strength" in terms of its condition for strict preference. On the one hand, it disallows cases like $(3,3,1)\sim (1,1,0)$, which is permissible under the weak version above. On the other hand, your definition (1) allows for cases like $(3,3,1)\sim(3,1,0)$, which is not permissible under the strict version a la MWG/Kreps.

Which version to use would depend on the context rather than the general meanings conveyed by the labels "weak" and "strong"/"strict".

Comment: Just one follow-up: Acc. to your definition of weak monotonicity, $(3,3,1) \sim (1,1,0)$ is allowed. [The definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_preferences) doesn't seem to allow it. This also seems to be the definition given by Rubinstein (in his lecture notes). Which definition is used more often? (Just checked that Kreps' definition of weak monotonicity is same as (2).)

Comment: @monotone: I updated the last part of my answer. Let me know if it's unclear.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies my doubt.